# Datatables date range filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How to add date range filter..

like **From-To** .

I got working regular search and pagination, etc..
But I dont know how to make date range filter.

I'm using Datatables 1.10.11 version.

My code:

```
var oTable;

function callFilesTable($sPaginationType, $bPaginate, $bFilter, $iDisplayLength, $fnSortcol, $fnSortdir){

    $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
        sSortAsc  : 'header headerSortDown',
        sSortDesc : 'header headerSortUp',
        sSortable : 'header'
    }); 

    oTable = $('#sort').DataTable({
        dom : '<"table-controls-top"fl>rt<"table-controls-bottom"ip>',
        pagingType : $sPaginationType,
        paging : $bPaginate,
        searching : $bFilter,
        pageLength : $iDisplayLength,
        order : [ [$fnSortcol, $fnSortdir] ],
        columnDefs : [
            { 
                width      : '50%',
                targets    : [ 2 ],
                orderable  : true,
                searchable : true,
                type       : 'natural'
            },
            { 
                width      : '10%',
                targets   : [ 3 ],
                orderable : true
            },
            { 
                width      : '20%',
                targets   : [ 4 ],
                orderable : true
            },
            { 
                targets    : ['_all'], 
                orderable  : false,
                searchable : false
            }
        ],
        language : paginationTemplate,
        drawCallback : function() {

            checkSelecta();
            placeHolderheight();

            // hide pagination if we have only one page
            var api = this.api();
            var pageinfo = api.page.info();
            var paginateRow = $(this).parent().find('.dataTables_paginate');  

            if (pageinfo.recordsDisplay <= api.page.len()) {
                paginateRow.css('display', 'none');
            } else {
                paginateRow.css('display', 'block');
            }
        }
    });

    oTable.on( 'length.dt', function ( e, settings, len ) {
        updateSession({ iDisplayLength: len });
    });
}
```

And I'm using NaturalSort 0.7 version.

Comment: there is a range plugin on the datatables site, did you take a look at it? https://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

Comment: @Bindrid Yes, but not working. Getting error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
    at Array.<anonymous> (range_dates.js:30)

Comment: I am playing with  it. If I get mine working I will post it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I got mine working base on https://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html.   Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/2bkbx2y3/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            var min = $('#min').datepicker('getDate');
            var max = $('#max').datepicker('getDate');
            var startDate = new Date(data[4]);
            if (min == null && max == null) return true;
            if (min == null && startDate <= max) return true;
            if (max == null && startDate >= min) return true;
            if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) return true;
            return false;
        }
    );

    $('#min').datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
    $('#max').datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
    $('#min, #max').change(function () {
        table.draw();
    });
});
```

Comment: But in your jsfiddle I changed dates to dd/mm/yyyy and its not working... and also if changing datepicker date format..

Comment: updated jsfidddle https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/2bkbx2y3/9/   If you are using yyyy in jquery datepicker, that is part of the problem. Each y represents 2 places it should be dd/mm/yy.

Comment: @Bindrid elegant solution. Thank you. Regarding the `dd/mm/yy` format, I am not sure why you need the extra code. Javascript Date object works with either format (see https://jsfiddle.net/2bkbx2y3/123/).

Comment: The example, as written, requires column number 4 to be a date column.  It can be altered to check any column for a valid date then apply the filter to it.

Comment: nice buddy.  great answer

Answer (score -1):

Following one using momentsjs, the advantage of momentsjs is we can compare different types of date/date time as simple

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
            var min  = $('#min-date').val()
            var max  = $('#max-date').val()
            var createdAt = data[0] || 0; // Our date column in the table
            //createdAt=createdAt.split(" ");
            var startDate   = moment(min, "DD/MM/YYYY");
            var endDate     = moment(max, "DD/MM/YYYY");
            var diffDate = moment(createdAt, "DD/MM/YYYY");
            //console.log(startDate);
            if (
              (min == "" || max == "") ||
              (diffDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate))


            ) {  return true;  }
            return false;

        }
    );
```